# What is a valid way to make a row on content clickable in terms of accessibility?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, accessibility, clickable

I'm trying to make a widget that can most easily be described as a clickable bootstrap media object list accessible. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/media-object/#media-list The original code has the js click event tied to the list item element itself.

My first thought was to wrap everything inside the list item element in a button element and attach my click event to the button. This gives the list item focus and acts how I would want it to. But then I read that it's bad practice to have things like divs or h tags inside a button tag.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="media" onclick="myFunction">
    <img src="..." class="mr-3" alt="...">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">List-based media object</h5>
      More info
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**VS**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <button type="button" class="media" onclick="myFunction" disabled="isDisabled()">
      <img src="..." class="mr-3" alt="...">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">List-based media object</h5>
      More info
      </div>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So at this point is there another way to make the entire list item row clickable with semantic html, or is my best option to add role=button, onkeypress events for the spacebar and enter, custom active/disabled classes, and set tabIndex to the li tag?

Edit: Perhaps another way to think of the design is the with this component https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/list-group/#links-and-buttons. Basically the design I'm trying to maintain is a stack of clickable rows, where each row contains an image and a couple short lines of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point in having a heading within a button or a link. If you have a heading, it should represent the page structure.

You can easily solve your "problem" by wrapping the "More info" element in a `button` or a link. Keyboard users will be able to focus the button, and mouse users will be able to choose between the button or clicking on the whole list element wrapper.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li class="media" onclick="myFunction">
    <img src="..." class="mr-3" alt="...">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">List-based media object</h5>
      <button title="More info about List-based media object">More info</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The point is to maintain the original design of a clickable row as much as possible. I agree a heading inside a button is weird and could be changes to a span with different styles.

But to your solution, perhaps what I'm asking for is an elegant way to smash a square peg into a round hole. I'm new to thinking in terms of accessibility and you may be correct in that the design itself is just not accessible no matter how it's dressed up.

Comment: @Dookie67 Look closer, the row is still clickable ;) You can perfectly have a row mouse clickable while handling keyboard accessibility differently.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends of how closely you want to follow the rules of semantic development and if you plan to support a page enabled for the blind and visually impaired.

The `<a>` should always be used for navigation from one page to another.

The `<button>` and `<input type="button>` should only be used to submit a form or for on-screen activities, like opening and closing a dialog, etc.

If you really want to follow the rules then allowing the user to click on an element other then buttons, input fields and select drop-downs is frowned upon. Screen readers, that are used by those visually impaired do much better if you use the correct element for the job.

Also, don't over do your DOM putting elements inside of elements without a good reason should be avoided. It just adds clutter.

Comment: That's what I was reading between the two, but this raises another dilemma which may stray too far from the original question. The click action will either open a dialog or navigate to a new page depending on context. (Mainly if the other page exists) I figured a button was more appropriate because of the extra logic there, but the more common action will be navigating to a new page, which in turn makes my doubt my button choice.

Comment: Having said what I did I will add that Google doesn't even follow this rule with gmail. But if it were me I would either just use the `<a>` tag in all situations for your code or I would try to determine if the page exists before rendering.